# locate places on google map using PIN code number in INDIA

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview

I'm trying to locate places on google map using PIN code numbers so my question is, is it possible to locate places on google map using PIN code in India?

Comment: https://google.com/maps/place/[PINCODE] You can also use Google Geocoding API.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={API_KEY}&components=postal_code:110011
```

And if you are more interested in getting the state and district you can use

```
https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/110011
```

This will yield something like this , and it is free to use

```
[
  {
    "Message": "Number of pincode(s) found:3",
    "Status": "Success",
    "PostOffice": [
      {
        "Name": "Nirman Bhawan",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Delivery",
        "Circle": "Delhi",
        "District": "Central Delhi",
        "Division": "New Delhi Central",
        "Region": "Delhi",
        "Block": "New Delhi",
        "State": "Delhi",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "110011"
      },
      {
        "Name": "South Avenue",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
        "Circle": "Delhi",
        "District": "Central Delhi",
        "Division": "New Delhi Central",
        "Region": "Delhi",
        "Block": "New Delhi",
        "State": "Delhi",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "110011"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Udyog Bhawan",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
        "Circle": "Delhi",
        "District": "Central Delhi",
        "Division": "New Delhi Central",
        "Region": "Delhi",
        "Block": "New Delhi",
        "State": "Delhi",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "110011"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```